# Query not fetching record, problem at trunc() function

Tags: sql

I am fetching record on behalf of `login_id` and `DOB`, I wrote a below query,
query running fine until u.login_id='101003' but not working at `trunc()` function

please help me

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    e.emp_id,
    e.name emp_name,
    e.mobile_no mob_no,
    e.alt_mobile_no,
    e.verify_status,
    u.status,
    e.relief_type
FROM
    userdetail u
    JOIN employee e ON u.user_id = e.emp_id
WHERE
        u.login_id ='1011003'
    AND
        trunc(e.dob) = TO_DATE('01/11/85','DD/MM/YYYY')
    AND (
            e.relief_type IS NULL
        OR
            e.relief_type = 4
    );
```

Entire query running fine if I commented

```
AND trunc(e.dob) = TO_DATE('01/11/85','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Apparently user 1011003 is **not** born on November 1, 1985

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: What data type is the column `dob`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this won't work until you add correct format of TRUNC.

Syntax: `TRUNC(date, format)`

You can use `TRUNC(date, 'MM')` or `TRUNC(date, 'YYYY')` or other formats which suites your requirement.

You can refer below link.
http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-date-functions/oracle-trunc/

Comment: `trunc(date)` is absolutely valid in Oracle. It's equivalent to `trunc(date, 'day')`